# What does {# content #} do in a Markdown file or a HTML file?

Tags: markdown

I have a question regarding a Markdown syntax...

What does {# content #} do in a Markdown file or a HTML file? Is it a comment?

Also what does {% content %} do? Is it a variable?

Example:

```
<p> `{% block toggle %}<p>
<label for="devsite-radio-objc">Objective-C</label>
<input type="radio" class="devsite-navigating-radio"value="swift">
</p>{% endblock %}{# toggle #}`
```

Comment: I have never worked with Markdown, but based on the example you have shown, the pairs of {% and %} seem to be template blocks. endblock is a big clue. Also, the pairs of {# and #} seem to be comment blocks.

Comment: Penny, is my comment worthy to become an answer?

Comment: @LajosArpad sorry that I forgot to accept your answer. Just did it! :)

Answer (score 1):

That's not Markdown.

The [original Markdown syntax](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) doesn't include anything like this. There are other popular versions of Markdown like [GFM](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/), [MultiMarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/) and [PHP Markdown](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/), but none introduce this kind of syntax.

It looks like something in the [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/) / [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/) / [Liquid](http://liquidmarkup.org/) / [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) / [Swig](https://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/) family of templating languages.

In the languages I have used `{# … #}` is indeed used for [comments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/#comments). These comments would generally not be included in the HTML output at all. Compare this with `<!-- HTML comments -->` which don't display in the rendered page, but are included in the HTML source.

`{% … %}` is generally used for [tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/#tags) and `{{ … }}`, which you haven't asked about, are used for [variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/#variables). Without knowing the specific language you're using it's hard to tell you much more than this. Different engines will have different available tags.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you so much for the answer! Actually i have one more follow-up question about one yaml syntax...I know that the indentation and structure is fairly important in yaml, So if I see the syntax `- description: > Build a map for your app using 3D buildings.`, does it matter if the "Build a map for your app using 3D buildings" follows after the greater than sign or if there's a line break in between(meaning the string starts a new line with indentation)?

Comment: @Penny, in general [Stack Overflow works best when each question is submitted separately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts). That's especially true here, since your YAML snippet is very hard to read in a comment. Please submit it in a new question, where you can properly indent the code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl+K or clicking the `{}` button.